# Hyperbolic integral of the second kind

Tags: scipy, special-functions

The elliptic integral of the second kind is given by
$$
E(t,m) = \int_{0}^t \sqrt{1-m \sin(s)^2} \operatorname{ds} 
$$
and there is for instance a scipy function [ellipeinc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ellipeinc.html#scipy.special.ellipeinc) that computes it.

The following formula comes up in the parametrization of constant negatively curved surfaces of rotation.
$$
H(t,m) := \int_{0}^t \sqrt{1-m \sinh(s)^2} \operatorname{ds} 
$$

Note that if we allow complex numbers, then $H(t,m) = E(it,im)$. But `ellipeinc` does not allow complex inputs.

- Is there a commonly accepted name for this "hyperbolic integral of the second kind" $H$?
- Is there a way to compute $H(t,1)$ using scipy functions, or other methods? How would one compute it efficiently (in Python)?

Comment: Any restrictions on $m\sinh^2 t$?

Comment: The [Arb library](https://arblib.org/acb_elliptic.html#legendre-incomplete-elliptic-integrals) offers `acb_elliptic_e_inc()`, which evaluates the Legendre incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind. The function's arguments are of type `acb_t`, i.e. complex numbers. The library's author notes in a relevant [publication](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06725): "The definitions for complex variables do not appear to be standardized in the literature, but following the conventions used in Mathematica [31], we may fix an interpretation ..."

Comment: Isn't $E$ implemented for complex numbers in `mpmath`?